# Debug JS errors generated in webbrowser control from Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8

I'm having a Windows Phone 8 app which uses a WebBrowser Control to access a link. The content of the page behaves differently than on other browsers like Chrome from Android or Safari from iOS (I'm assuming because of an incompatibility with Internet Explorer 10).
Is there a way I can see the JS errors from the web browser inside the app? Or any other way to debug the web browser?

Comment: If you have access to the javascript, than inject a function that will route the javascript errors to your managed code. Read more about this at this link.  http://studentguru.gr/b/eloy/archive/2013/10/24/a-deep-overview-of-the-webbrowser-control-windows-phone-8-notes-amp-guidelines